# JQuery AutoComplete Append to Open List

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, widget

I tested the JQuery autocomplete UI widget and noticed that the autocomplete has extremely poor performance in IE when dealing with large amount of data. My client uses internet explorer 7.

I found a solution to mitigate the performance issue. Instead of returning all the matches of the autocomplete search I only return the first 40 matches. Code below

```
source: function (request, response) {
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                var select_el = select.get(0); // get dom element
                var rep = new Array(); // response array
                var maxRepSize = 40; // maximum response size
                // simple loop for the options
                var looper = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < select_el.length; i++) {
                    var text = select_el.options[i].text;
                    if (!request || request == '') {
                        // add element to result array
                        rep[looper++] = {
                            label: text,
                            value: text,
                            option: select_el.options[i]
                        };
                    }
                    else if ( select_el.options[i].value && matcher.test(text)   ) {
                        // add element to result array
                        rep[looper++] = {
                            label: text,
                            value: text,
                            option: select_el.options[i]
                        };
                    }
                    if ( rep.length > maxRepSize ) {
                        needMoreItems = true;
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                 // send response
                 response( rep );
            },
```

The client asked me to append a "More Results" item to the autocomplete list. If there were more than 40 items that matched the search the "More Results" item would appear of at the bottom of the list. If a user clicked on the "More Results" item, the autocomplete drop down would expand to include the next 40 matches. I experimented with the jQuery autocomplete and I was able to populate the auto suggest list with the next 40 items but when the user clicked on one of the dynamically added items, I could not bind the click event to the Select Event of the autocomplete UI widget. Code below:

```
open: function( event, ui ) {

                if (needMoreItems) {

                    needMoreItems = false;
                    $('<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" id="yoADDMORE" ><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">... more available<br/><br/></a></li>')
                    .bind({
                        click: function(e) {
                            var appendHtml = '';
                            var select_el = select.get(0);
                            var maxRepSize = 40; // maximum response size
                            // simple loop for the options
                            var looper = 0;
                            for (var i = 41; i < select_el.length; i++) {
                                appendHtml += '<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">' + select_el.options[i].text + '</a></li>';

                                if ( looper ++ > maxRepSize ) {
                                    needMoreItems = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (needMoreItems)
                            appendHtml += '<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem" id="yoADDMORE" ><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">... more available<br/><br/></a></li>';
                            $('#yoADDMORE').remove();
                            $('ul.ui-autocomplete').html($('ul.ui-autocomplete').html() + appendHtml);

                            $('ul.ui-autocomplete > li')
                            .bind({
                                mouseenter: function(e) {
                                    // Hover event handler
                                   $("> a",this).attr('class','ui-corner-all ui-state-hover');
                                },
                                mouseleave: function(e) {
                                    // Hover event handler
                                    $("> a",this).attr('class','ui-corner-all');
                                }
                            });

                        },
                        mouseenter: function(e) {
                            // Hover event handler
                           $("> a",this).attr('class','ui-corner-all ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        mouseleave: function(e) {
                            // Hover event handler
                            $("> a",this).attr('class','ui-corner-all');
                        }



                   })
                   .appendTo('ul.ui-autocomplete');

               }                    

            },
```

Links to jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/eyecode/sX4Ba/
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you check the error logs? You are getting a 'cannot call method `data` of null' error.

Comment: Basically I append items to the autocomplete list manually I receive an error "ui.data.item" is null in the "select: function (event, ui)" event

Comment: Have you solved this yet? I will have some time later today to look at it.

Comment: Hi, Yes I have a solution. I will post be soon. Vic

Comment: Please post your solution, Victor. :)

Comment: Hi, I have the solution at work will post tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

In order to list the top 20 options with a "More .." at the bottom of the first 20 items. Once a user presses "More .." link. All the items will be displayed in the drop down.

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.typeaheadtextbox", {
        _create: function () {
            var self = this,
            select = this.element.hide(),
            theWidth = select.width(),
            selected = select.children(":selected"),
            value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
      var _searchItem = '';
      var _more = false;
      var _lastIndex = 0;
      var _maxSize = 20;
      var _rep = null;
            var input = this.input = $("<input id='" + select[0].id + "_jq' style=\"width: " + theWidth + "px\">")
            .insertAfter(select)
            .val(value)
            .autocomplete({
                delay: 10,
                minLength: 0,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                    var j = 0;
          _rep = response;
          _searchItem = request.term;
          var select_el = select.get(0); // get dom element
          var rep = new Array(); // response array
          for (var i = 0; i < select_el.length; i++) {
            var text = select_el.options[i].text;
            if (select_el.options[i].value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text))) {
              j++;
              if (j > _maxSize) {
                                _more = true;
                                _lastIndex = i;
                                break;
                            }
              // add element to result array
              rep[(j - 1)] = {
                                label: text.replace(new RegExp("^(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(_searchItem) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"), value: text, option: select_el.options[i]
                            };
            }
          }
          return response(rep);
                },
                autoFocus:true,
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    if (_more) {
                        _more = false;
                        $('<li class="ui-menu-item_more" role="menuitem" id="' + select.get(0).id + '_ADDMORE_' + _lastIndex + '" ><a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"><img width="16" src="Content/themes/base/images/icon-search-small.png"/> <strong>View All</strong></a></li>')
                        .bind({
                            click: function(e) {
                                var response = _rep;
                                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(_searchItem), "i");
                                var select_el = select.get(0); // get dom element
                                var rep = new Array(); // response array
                                var j = 0;
                                for (var i = 0; i < select_el.length; i++) {
                                    var text = select_el.options[i].text;
                                    if (select_el.options[i].value && (!_searchItem || matcher.test(text))) {
                                        // add element to result array
                                        rep[j++] = {
                                            label: text.replace(new RegExp("^(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(_searchItem) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"), value: text, option: select_el.options[i]
                                        };
                                    }
                                }
                                $(this).remove();
                                return _rep(rep);
                            },
                            mouseenter: function(e) { $("> a",this).attr('class','ui-corner-all ui-state-hover'); },
                            mouseleave: function(e) { $("> a",this).attr('class','ui-corner-all');}
                        })
                        .appendTo('ul.ui-autocomplete');
                        _lastIndex = 0;
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    self._trigger("selected", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });
                },
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.item) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                            valid = false;
                        select.children("option").each(function () {
                            if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                                this.selected = valid = true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if (!valid) {
                            // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                            $(this).val("");
                            select.val("");
                            input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all");
            input.data("autocomplete")._renderMenu = function( ul, items ) {
            var self = this; var htm = ''; var beginHtm = '<li><a>'; var endHtm = '</a></li>';
          for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
                htm += beginHtm + items[i].label +  endHtm;
          }
          ul[0].innerHTML = htm;
          var liTags = ul[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
          for(var i=0;i<liTags.length;i++) {
            $(liTags[i]).data("item.autocomplete", items[i]);
          }
          return true;
        };
        },
        destroy: function () {
            this.input.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        },
        clear: function () {
            this.element.val("");
            this.input.val("");
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```